# Aggregating flat objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a lot of Objects with the same flat structure but different integer values.
The problem is I do not know the structure, I only know that it is consistent.

Now I want to aggregate them to just one Object.

So I have a function that adds up all elements of two objects.

```
function objectAddition(s1, s2) {
    for(i in s2) {
        s1[i] = (s1[i] || 0) + s2[i];   
    }
}
```

and call this for each Object.

```
var total = {};
for(i in objs) {
    objectAddition(total, objs[i]);
}
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: This code is unlikely to be a performance bottleneck ever. So it makes sense for you to start solving the *real problems*, not imaginary.

Answer (score 0):

You definately want to look at [LoDash](https://lodash.com).

```
// the third parameter to _.reduce is its accumulator, it's set to {} as was your `total`
var total = _.reduce(objs, function(acc, item){
       // acc is the accumulator, it becomes the thisArg of the _.forEach
       _.forEach(_.keys(item), function(key){
          this[key] = (this[key] || 0 ) + item[key];
       }, acc);
       return acc;
     }, {});
```

Comment: The question was, "is there a faster way to do this?". I wonder if this is faster.

Comment: @torazaburo, you're right. I misread "better" for "faster".   Also _.reduce isn't chainable.